# Typescript - TypeError this.renderCell is not a function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I am writing a Web app using `ReactJS` and `Typescript`.

I wrote the following code inside my class

```
class FractionComponent extends React.Component<any, FractionState>{

constructor(props: any) {
  super(props);
  this.state = this.createNew();
}

renderBoard() {
const strBoardId = "board";

return (
  <Board
    id={strBoardId}
    itemsRender={this.renderItems}
    rowsNumber={this.state.rowsNumber}
    columnsNumber={this.state.columnsNumber}
    onClick={() => this.handleClick()}
  />
);
```

}

```
renderCell(id: string, coords: FractionCoord) {
return (
  <div key={id} className="page_boardCell" />
);
}

renderItems(rows: number, columns: number) {
  let rowsArray = [];
  let columnsArray: string[] = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
    columnsArray = []
    for (let j = 0; j < columns; j++) {
      columnsArray.push(`${i}${j}`);
    }
    rowsArray.push(columnsArray)
  }
return (
  rowsArray.map((row, ri) => (
    <div key={ri} className="page_boardRow">
      {columnsArray.map((cellId, index) => this.renderCell(cellId, { "a": ri, "b": index })
      )}
    </div>
  ))
);
```

}

```
render() {
 return (
   <React.Fragment>
       {this.renderBoard()}
   </React.Fragment>
 )
}
```

}

```
    function Board(props: BoardProps) {
  var classes = ["fractionPage_board"];
  if (props.selected) { classes.push("fractionPage_selectedSquare"); }
  if (props.isCellError) { classes.push("fractionPage_error"); }

  return (
    <div key={props.id} className={classes.join(" ")} onClick={props.onClick} style={{ ...props.cellStyle }}>
      {props.itemsRender(props.rowsNumber, props.columnsNumber)}
 
    </div>
  );
}

interface BoardProps { id: string, onClick: any, itemsRender: any, columnsNumber: number, rowsNumber: number }
```

But it gives me this error

```
TypeError: this.renderCell is not a function
```

When I remove `renderCell` function and embedd the code directly in `renderItems` it works.

WHat's the problem  could be?

Thank you.

**EDIT**
I forget to say that I am passing`renderItems` as a `props` to another component.

Comment: Add the rest of your component to the question.

Comment: Done please check it

Comment: `FractionState`, `createNew`, `Board`, `handleClick`, `FractionCoord` are all missing and several keys from `BoardProps` are missing.

Answer (score 0):

The callback function passed inside map is an arrow function, in which `this` won't refer to the class instance. Change it to a regular function syntax, and things should work fine

```
{columnsArray.map(function(cellId, index) { return this.renderCell(cellId, { "a": ri, "b": index })})}
```

Comment: It's giving me this error : 'this' implicitly has type 'any' because it does not have a type annotation.